# How to set up all controllers' view to suit safe area

Tags: ios, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

My app now supports iOS7.0+, and I want to cover the area outside of safe area with black color, so the bottom 34 height area should look well. But I get so many controllers to change, is there a shortcut?
I've searched many guides, but it all just introduced how to created a new pretty controller view in iphone X. What I want to do make all old views behave well inside safe area.

----------Update
I tried a way, add a black view to the key window, and set the additional insets in customized root controller, but 1) the bottom aligned button is covered by the black view when a controller view does not contain the scroll view. 2) If scroll view is contained, then how would the additional insets effect the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

**Project migration to iPhone X**

1) Add new splash screen for `iPhone X` resolution **(1125 × 2436)**

2) After adding new splash scree for `iPhone X`, UI elements like `UINavigationController`,`UITableView`, and `UICollectionView` automatically adapt according `iPhone X` device.

3) If you have used any custom control then, You have to do design according to standard.

4) In case of auto layout just checked  `safearealayoutguide` in `storyboard` file

4) In case of auto sizing, You have to manage all control another then above.

**Note:**
If existing project was made with Auto layout then migration of project easily.In case Auto Sizing then migration tough as compare to auto layout.

Please find more reference from Below.

[reference1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/)

[reference2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204)

Comment: I got a compiling error when check the safearealayoutguide. I updated the question, met some problems when answer the question myself

Comment: Please check deployment target, It will be greater or equal to iOS => 8.0